# How to implement sharding in MongoDB (3.6)

Tags: mongodb, sharding, sharing

I was doing Sharding in MongoDB (with the 2.6 version) and the commands that i followed was the next (I listed them in a photo) and the commands give me positivo results.
But the Problem that I have is that in the newest version (3.6) the Command: `mongod --configsvr --dbpath...` (in the photo is the step 3) is not working, I looked for it in the MongoDB Page and didn't found anything about that.

I hope guys you can help me. Please 
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNETk.png).

Comment: Hi Diana Garcia, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've got a bit of advice about your question: Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your commands, copy and paste or type the actual commands and results into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB 3.6 , you should specify the name of the replica set in the command for starting the config server :

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplicaName --dbpath mongoDB2/shard/configFolderName --port portNumberOfTheConfigServer
```

**Note1 :** The `configFolderName` folder should be already created , then you have to create the replica set (you can create it in a  single machine, using different ports for test purposes )

**Note1 :** After starting it, to create the replica set of the config server, you connect to this later , using `mongo --port portNumberOfTheConfigServer`, and then you do :

```
rs.initiate({
 _id : “congigReplicaName”,
configsvr : true,
members : [{ _id:0 , host : “localhost:27111”}]
})
```